# Disable a css rule on IE

Tags: css, background-image

i wonder if you know a way to able or disable a css rule when client has ie.

I've this style

```
 #number_one{
    background-image: url("../img/pins/1.png");    
    top: 250px;
    left: 115px;    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/pins/1.png',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/pins/1.png',sizingMethod='scale')";

}
```

I want background-image to work on all browser except IE, becuase Filters will do the background-image job.

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way (without the need for multiple separate stylesheets [which works too, by the way]) is to replace your `<html>` tag with this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
 <html class="ie">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
 <html class="normal">
<![endif]-->
```

And in your CSS, use this to target only IE:

```
html.ie #number_one{
  background-image:none;
}
```

Or use this to target all browsers except IE:

```
 html.normal #number_one{
    background-image: url("../img/pins/1.png");    
    top: 250px;
    left: 115px;    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/pins/1.png',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/pins/1.png',sizingMethod='scale')";

}
```

Comment: Why the -1? Care to explain?

Comment: this certainly isn't worth -3. It seem pretty much identical to @GurpreetSingh's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Include this in head for IE specific styles and overwrite CSS here:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

It is also feasible to target each version of IE separately:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie6-only.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This opens an extra HTTP connection you don't need

Comment: This is definitely one possible solution & you can always use this CSS to target IE.

Comment: True; problem is I still can't figure out why mine isn't according to some people here

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create an IE-only stylesheet, and change the class accordingly using this method I found:

To target IE using conditional comments, just add this line to the >head< tags of your HTML file:

```
1   <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie6.css"      type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
2    
3   <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

These conditional comments will be ignored by every other browser so only IE 6 and IE 7 respectively will load these stylesheets. Now all you need to do is create the files on your server and override whatever CSS rules are messing with IE’s headers.