# How to ignore a specific css class property only on IE

Tags: html, css, angular2-template

One of the css classes I am using is:

```
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

which works fine in chrome. 
But, for some reason, I see the UI a bit messed up and if I remove display: inline-block, it looks good on IE, but then its messed up in chrome. Is there a way to ignore using display: inline-block from this class when its IE and use only when on chrome?

Comment: Not sure but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383256/disable-a-css-rule-on-ie) helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet)

Comment: I have provided a simple solution using javascript. You can test it in IE and any other browser to see it work. Let me know if I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with javascript. The first thing you're going to want to do is check to make sure the browser is Internet Explorer. If it is, you can set the inline display style which will override what you have in your css file. I'm not sure whether you want to set the elements to `display:inline;` or `display:block;` so I will set them to `display:block;` in the following code snippet, just to show you how it can be done.

```js
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode) {
  var myTestElements = document.querySelectorAll(".test");

  for (var i = 0; i < myTestElements.length; i++) {
    myTestElements[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}
else {
  console.log("Not IE");
}
```

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test1</div>
  <div class="test">Test2</div>
  <div class="test">Test3</div>
  <div class="test">Test4</div>
```

First I used an if statement to see if the browser is IE. Inside that I selected all the elements with `document.querySelectorAll(".test");`. Then in a for loop, I iterated through all the `.test` elements and added an inline style of `display:block;`. **NOTE**: The else statement is not necessary. I just added that for the purposes of this code snippet. I hope that helps.